# How to rewrite this code with `for` loop?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I have a radiobutton created with tkinter and the radiobutton's commad is :

```
 def FieldsetChanger ():
        lbl1_1.configure(state="enable")
        Entry1_1.configure(state="enable")
        lbl2_1.configure(state="enable")
        Entry2_1.configure(state="enable")
```

can I rewrite this function with `for` loop?

Comment: You could create a list with those as elements and just call `.configure(state="enable")` on every list item.

Comment: ```.configure(state="normal")``` its is ```normal``` and not ```enable``` @SaatvikRamani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store those elements in an array (e.g list) and iterate over them:

```py
my_arr = [lbl1_1, Entry1_1, lbl2_1, Entry2_1]

def FieldsetChanger ():
    for element in my_arr:
        element.configure(state="enable")
```

Comment: Not really important but I think that a tuple is better because it's faster. From a quick test that I did, I found that creating a tuple can be 10 times faster.

Comment: @TheLizzard yes. I know, but I suggested list since he probably creating these objects and appends them into the list, which is impossible with tuple. (He might be using listcomp but then he wouldn’t ask this question).

Comment: Oh that's why. But then would it be a good idea to move the `my_arr = ...` outside of the function?